# What is the "Mathematica" function for plotting a single variable inequality?

Tags: math-software, mathematica

I was just wondering, how do I plot a single variable inequality in Mathematica?

For example, we could use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) for plotting an inequality like $x^3+4x+9 > 0$ and see something like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%20x%5E3%2b4x%2b9%20%3E%200). How could we do the same thing in Mathematica?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
Plot[x^3+4x+9, {x,-2,2}, Filling->{1->{Axis, {White, LightBlue}}}]
```

Or, if you have two functions, and want where first curve is above the second, use

```
Plot[{x^3+4x+9,6x^2}, {x,-2,2}, Filling->{1->{{2}, {White, LightBlue}}}]
```

for example.

Comment: Could you explain the plot?Especially the filling side,I haven't did anything using filling before.

Comment: Well, I suggest you read about the Filling option in the excellent help that accompanies Mathematica. Press F1, search for Filling.

Answer (score 2):

There is also `RegionPlot[]`:

```
RegionPlot[x^3 + 4 x + 9 > y, {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 25}]
```

plots the part in blue.